# Convergence of an improper integral with parameter

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

For fixed $s>0$, the function $f(k)$ is defined by
$$ f(k)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-sx} \cdot \frac{e^{-\frac{k^2}{4x}}}{\sqrt{\pi x}}\,\,dx$$

Show that it is well defined, that is, the improper integral converges $\forall k \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Take limit as $x\to0$ and $x\to+\infty$ and see how rapidly the integrand converges to zero due to the exponential functions.

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. If there is some context added, I can post a detailed answer (this integral has a simple closed form).

Answer (score 0):

Hints: For $x\in [0,1]$ the integrand is $\le \dfrac{1}{\sqrt x}.$ For $x\ge 1,$  the integrand is $\le e^{-sx}.$

Answer (score 0):

What's best than an explicit evaluation? For any $s>0$
$$f(k)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-sx^2-\frac{k^2}{4x^2}\right)\,dx =\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}e^{-k\sqrt{s}}$$
by [Glasser's master theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GlassersMasterTheorem.html).